# Where is bitcoin.exe?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, windows

I need to make a request through cmd.exe (commandline), but the only .exe file I can find is bitcoin-qt.exe, which doesn't respond to "getinfo", "getaddressbalance", etc. How can I find bitcoin.exe to make these requests?

Comment: You can also use Help->Console if you're just exploring how the commands work

Answer (score 1):

The same executable is both the server and the client. Run it as a server, and then you can use it to issue commands like `getinfo` to the server instance.